# Dynamic loading of python modules

Tags: python, dynamic, python-import

In python how do you dynamically add modules to a package while your program is running.

I want to be able to add modules to the package directory from an outside process, and be able to use those new modules in my program:

```
import package

def doSomething(name):
    pkg = __import__("package." + name)
    mod = getattr(pkg, name)
    mod.doSomething()
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 62):

Your code is almost correct.

See [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function.

```
def doSomething(name):
    name = "package." + name
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=[''])
    mod.doSomething()
```

Comment: __import__ returns the module, so you can do "mod = __import__(name)" rather than having to look it up in sys.modules.

Comment: "When the name variable is of the form package.module, normally, the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, not the module named by name."

Comment: Clarification to Brian's comment... __import__ returns the package, not the module.  So, you need to either lookup the module in sys.modules or use my technique (listed in another answer) to get the module from the package.

Comment: Also, looks like sys.modules holds the fully-qualified module name.  So, you need to lookup 'package.'+name in sys.modules.

Comment: Edited to use fromlist argument.  Passing something (anything) in fromlist causes __import__ to return the module you want directly.

Comment: Rolled back one change. Passing `fromlist=[]` has the same effect as not specifying `fromlist` at all. Adding empty string solves this problem.

Answer (score 23):

Bastien already answered the question, anyway you may find useful this function I use to load all the modules from a subfolder in a dictionary:

```
def loadModules():
    res = {}
    import os
    # check subfolders
    lst = os.listdir("services")
    dir = []
    for d in lst:
        s = os.path.abspath("services") + os.sep + d
        if os.path.isdir(s) and os.path.exists(s + os.sep + "__init__.py"):
            dir.append(d)
    # load the modules
    for d in dir:
        res[d] = __import__("services." + d, fromlist = ["*"])
    return res
```

This other one is to instantiate an object by a class defined in one of the modules loaded by the first function:

```
def getClassByName(module, className):
    if not module:
        if className.startswith("services."):
            className = className.split("services.")[1]
        l = className.split(".")
        m = __services__[l[0]]
        return getClassByName(m, ".".join(l[1:]))
    elif "." in className:
        l = className.split(".")
        m = getattr(module, l[0])
        return getClassByName(m, ".".join(l[1:]))
    else:
        return getattr(module, className)
```

A simple way to use those functions is this:

```
mods = loadModules()
cls = getClassByName(mods["MyModule"], "submodule.filepy.Class")
obj = cls()
```

Obviously you can replace all the "services" subfolder references with parameters.

Comment: about the question "__import__ load the package not the module" (I cannot comment Bastian's answer): actually __import__ load the module instead of the package when the fromlist parameter is used, even as [] (check my function)

Comment: loadModules() returns also *.pyc is it important?

Comment: uhm help for os.path.exists() don't say anything about a partial match, I feel it should _not_ return *.pyc files. anyway in this case I think it's not really important.

Answer (score 19):

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('my_package.my_module')
my_class = getattr(module, 'MyClass')
my_instance = my_class()
```

Answer (score 10):

One trick with Bastien's answer...  The `__import__()` function returns the package object, not the module object.  If you use the following function, it will dynamically load the module from the package and return you the module, not the package.

```
def my_import(name):
    mod = __import__(name)
    components = name.split('.')
    for comp in components[1:]:
        mod = getattr(mod, comp)
    return mod
```

Then you can do:

```
mod = my_import('package.' + name)
mod.doSomething()
```

Comment: Note that it's not "my" answer, I just added a bit of formatting to S. Lott's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To detect changes to a directory, on Linux, you can use [pyinotify](http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify) ([here](http://david-latham.blogspot.com/2008/06/python-inotify-pyinotify-how-to-watch.html) is a nice working example); on a Mac, [fsevents](http://www.wilcoxd.com/blog/pyobjc-20-fsevents.html) (via the PyObjC package that comes with your Mac); on Windows, [Directory Change Notifications](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) via [win32api](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/) (or the Python standard library `ctypes` module). AFAIK, nobody's wrapped up these various approaches into one portable package. (Of course, worst case, you can fall back to "lower tech" approaches such as periodic polling, as [Tim Golden's article](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html), perhaps with a touch of "alerts from an external process" via a signal, etc).

Once you do have the notification and the name of the new or modified module, the code you show in the question should work.

Answer (score -1):

Add the module directory to `sys.path` and use the normal `import` statement.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  The module name is specified by the user and the normal import doesn't seem to take a string.  Also, it won't detect the "new" modules.