# python catching NameError when loading module

Tags: python, exception, module, nameerror

I'm trying to catch any exceptions that happen when you cannot load a module. 
The current results are that the "except" block does not get executed.

```
import sys 
def loadModule(module):
   try: 
      import module
   except: 
      print """ 
      Cannot load %s
      For this script you will need: 
         cx_Oracle:  http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/
         pycrypto:   https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/
         paramiko:   http://www.lag.net/paramiko/
       """ % module
      sys.exit(1)

loadModule(cx_Oracle)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./temp_script.py", line 16, in <module>
    loadModule(cx_Oracle)
NameError: name 'cx_Oracle' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
loadModule(cx_Oracle)
```

What do you think you are passing to this function? There is nothing named `cx_Oracle` in the code so far. That's why you are getting a NameError. You aren't even getting into the function.

```
 import module
```

You can't pass variables to import, it interprets what you put in as the literal name of the module

In this case, I question that you even need a function. Just move the try/except to the module level and import cx_Oracle directly.

Just because I was curious, here is a way you can make a reusable exception-catching import function. I'm not sure when/how it would be useful, but here it is:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

@contextmanager
def safe_import(name):
    try:
        yield
    except:
        print 'Failed to import ' + name
        sys.exit(1)

with safe_import('cuckoo'):
    import cuckoo
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is happening when Python is trying to look up the `cx_Oracle` variable before the `loadModule` function can even be called.

If you want to keep your current strategy, you probably really want to be using something like [importlib.import_module](http://docs.python.org/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) so that you can import the module by name, like `import_module('cx_Oracle')`.

I'd suggest doing something like this instead:

```
try:
    import cx_Oracle
except ImportError:
    print "Can't load the Oracle module"
    dosomething()
```

in the top level of your module. That's the Pythonic way of handling this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Always think about which exception you want to catch. Do not overgeneralize by just coding `except:`. In this case, you want to catch the `ImportError`. The argument you want to pass to your function `loadModule` should be of type string, e.g. `loadModule('cx_Oracle')` (then you will get rid of the `NameError`). For loading modules dynamically within `loadModule` have a look at for example [Dynamic loading of python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951124/dynamic-loading-of-python-modules).