# Python: what does this codes do? "Module = type(sys)"

Tags: python-2.7

I have saw some python code for configuration somewhere, but i cant understand that.

here is the code:

```
import sys, os.path

Module = type(sys) # What does this line for? 

modules = {}

print dir(Module)

def load(fullpath, env={}, module=Module):
    try:
        code = open(fullpath).read()
    except IOError:
        raise ImportError, 'No module named %s' % fullpath

    filename = os.path.basename(fullpath)

    try:
        return modules[filename]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    #################################### 
    #### Most confused 

    m = module(filename) 
    m.__module_class__ = module
    m.__file__ = fullpath

    m.__dict__.update(env)

    exec compile(code, filename, 'exec') in m.__dict__
    ####################################

    modules[filename] = m

    return m


def unload(m):

    filename = os.path.basename(m.__file__)
    del modules[filename]

    return None


def reload(m):
    fullpath = m.__file__

    try:
        code = open(fullpath).read()
    except IOError:
        raise ImportError, 'No module named %s' % fullpath

    env = m.__dict__
    module_class = m.__module_class__

    filename = os.path.basename(fullpath)
    m = module_class(filename)

    m.__file__ = fullpath
    m.__dict__.update(env)
    m.__module_class__ = module_class

    exec compile(code, filename, 'exec') in m.__dict__
    modules[filename] = m

    return m
```

1. I cant understand why make the Module = type(sys)
2. what does the var m and its buildin method do , where can i find the doc?
3. why just define a dict var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code above the line:

```
Module = type(sys)
```

creates a variable of type module. You can open up an interpreter and type the following code:

```
import sys
Module = type(sys)
help(Module)
```

You will see the following:

> Help on class module in module **builtin**:
>
> class module(object)
> |  module(name[, doc])
> |
> |  Create a module object.
> |  The name must be a string; the optional doc argument can have any type.
> |
> |  Methods defined here:
> |
> |  **delattr**(...)
> |      x.**delattr**('name') <==> del x.name
> |
> |  **getattribute**(...)
> |      x.**getattribute**('name') <==> x.name
> |
> |  **init**(...)
> |      x.**init**(...) initializes x; see help(type(x)) for signature
> |
> |  **repr**(...)
> |      x.**repr**() <==> repr(x)
> ...

The load method, where you are most confused is basically, adding files to the module m and then compiling the code in those modules.

I don't know what it is that you are trying to achieve, by using this code, but there are much easier ways to dynamically load modules. For example:

[Dynamic loading of python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951124/dynamic-loading-of-python-modules)