# create instance of python class from a module in a specific package

Tags: python, import, module

So the idea is that I have a module with an object in it. I know the name of the class, but I need to instantiate an instance of it.

The module comes from a very specific package, and there may be other modules with the same name in different packages. I do know the package.

How can I create an instance of that class? I'm not typing this in, all of this is running in code.

Comment: Can you provide example in form of directory structure?

Comment: i think you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951124/dynamic-loading-of-python-modules/951678#951678) ?