# Dynamically import via variable a relative script in Python

Tags: python, python-import

In my main Python script, a web API is called. The result of that call determines what 'protocol' needs to run. These protocols are individual python scripts inside a subfolder called `protocols/`.

So, from my main script, how do I dynamically call one of these scripts? The script name is a variable coming from the API, and it's in a subfolder of the main script - not the standard library location.

I could use `subprocess.popen` or `os.system`, but I want everything to stay as in-house as possible.

There's gotta be a way to accomplish this within one Python instance, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python built-in function that can handle calling scripts.

It is called `execfile` and you can learn more about it at:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile

If I have a file called `testmeagain.py` with the contents:

```
print "test print"
```

You can do this without importing additional libraries:

```
In [1]: execfile("testmeagain.py")
test print
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run your main Python program from the directory, which see `protocols` as subfolder, you shall add empty `__init__.py` into `protocols` directory to make it a package.

Then you shall be able importing your protocol specific modules from there, e.g.

```
from protocols.http import process_it
```

Here I assume, you would have there some function named `process_it`

There are also other methods, how to import package with name defined in a variable as described e.g. in this SO answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951124/dynamic-loading-of-python-modules).

In your case it would look somehow like:

```
def process_it(protocol="http"):
    mod = __import__("protocols." + protocol)
    mod.process_it()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a possibility to accomplish this within one Python instance. It is possible to load individual python scripts dynamically as the following:

1. Load only the module dynamically with `importlib.import_module()`
2. Load a module and class dynamically with `getattr()`.

### **Alternative 1**

Use `importlib.import_module()`, if you only want to load the module dynamically. Let’s assume you have the following protocols in the subfolder *protocols*: 
*protocols/protocol_1.py* containing the following class:

```
class Protocol():
    # some protocol specific code
```

*protocols/protocol_2.py* containing the following class:

```
class Protocol():
    # some protocol specific code
```

First we define the dynamic variables with the protocol name that will be returned from the Web API:

```
module = 'protocols.protocol_1'
```

Then we import the importlib and load the module dynamically. The Protocol class has in both files the same class name but protocol specific code. Afterwards, we instantiate the api_protocol with the dynamically loaded Protocol:

```
import importlib

Protocol = importlib.import_module(module).Protocol

api_protocol = Protocol()
```

### **Alternative 2**

Use getattr, if you also want to load the class dynamically. Let’s assume you have the following protocols in the subfolder *protocols*:

*protocols/protocol_1.py* containing the following class:

```
class Protocol_1():
    # some protocol specific code
```

*protocols/protocol_2.py* containing the following class:

```
class Protocol_2():
    # some protocol specific code
```

First we define the dynamically variables with the protocol name that will be returned from the Web API:

```
module = 'protocols.protocol_1' 
class_name = 'Protocol_1'
```

Then we call the `__import__` function in order to load dynamically the *class* of a dynamic *module*. Afterwards we can create the new class with `getattr` and instantiate the api_protocol with the dynamically loaded Protocol:

```
mod = __import__(module, fromlist=[class_name])
Protocol = getattr(mod, class_name)
api_protocol = Protocol()
```